# Getting Null pointer exception

Tags: automated-testing, java, cucumber

I am new to Cucumber and I am trying a basic cucumber test.

I am getting the below error while running the test.

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   stepDefinitions.Test_steps.the_user_enters_the_username(Test_steps.java:39)
>     at ✽.the user enters the "abcd@gmail.com"
>   username(src/test/java/resources/features/Test.feature:16)

I have added 2 Scenario Outlines in a single Feature file.

Please find below Feature file.

```
Feature: creating a sample project 

Scenario Outline: Login to google and search different values 

    Given user open browser and launches "<Search>" 
    When the login page is displayed 
    Examples: Search 
        |       Search      | 
        |       https://www.facebook.com/   |       
Scenario Outline: search user 

    When the user enters the "<username>" username 
    And the user enters the "<password>" password 
    When the user clicks on login 
    Then search should login successfully. 
    Then closes the browser 
    Examples: username and password 
        |username       | password  |
        |abcd@gmail.com | Testing   |
```

Please find below my Step Definition:

**Code:**

```
@Given("^user open browser and launches \"([^\"]*)\"$")

public void user_open_browser_and_launches(String url) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get(url);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

    }

    @When("^the login page is displayed$")
    public void the_login_page_is_displayed() {

            driver.getTitle();
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

    }

    @When("^the user enters the \"([^\"]*)\" username$")
    public void the_user_enters_the_username(String username) {

        System.out.println(username);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='email']")).sendKeys(username);

    }

    @And("^the user enters the \"([^\"]*)\" password$")
    public void the_user_enters_the_password(String password) {

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='pass']")).sendKeys(password);

    }

    @When("^the user clicks on login$")
    public void the_user_clicks_on_login() {

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='submit']")).click();

    }

    @Then("^search should login successfully\\.$")
    public void search_should_login_successfully() {

        System.out.println("Page is loaded successfully");

    }

    @Then("^closes the browser$")
    public void closes_the_browser() throws InterruptedException {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.quit();


    }
```

Could you please let me know where I am going wrong.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is "driver" a class attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I execute my Automation code i find some flows in your way:
1. If you have a website to automate then there is no need to use 2 Scenario Outline's. 
2. Single scenario outline should have all scenarios required to automate.

I have divided your automation task in 3 parts 
1. Feature File 
2. Step Definition
3. Logical Implementation

Feature File:

Scenario Outline: Login to google and search different values

```
Given user open browser and launches "<Search>"
When the login page is displayed
When the user enters the "<username>" username
And the user enters the "<password>" password
When the user clicks on login
Then search should login successfully.
Then closes the browser

Examples:
  | Search                    | username       | password |
  | https://www.facebook.com/ | abcd@gmail.com | Testing  |
```

StepDefinition:

package com.stepdefinition;

```
import com.ibepages.StackExchangePage;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class StackExchange {


    StackExchangePage stackExchangePage = new StackExchangePage();


    @Given("^user open browser and launches \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void user_open_browser_and_launches(String url) throws Throwable {
        stackExchangePage.openURL(url);
    }

    @When("^the login page is displayed$")
    public void the_login_page_is_displayed() throws Throwable {

    }

    @When("^the user enters the \"([^\"]*)\" username$")
    public void the_user_enters_the_username(String username) throws Throwable {
        stackExchangePage.enterUserName(username);
    }

    @When("^the user enters the \"([^\"]*)\" password$")
    public void the_user_enters_the_password(String password) throws Throwable {
        stackExchangePage.enterPassword(password);
    }

    @When("^the user clicks on login$")
    public void the_user_clicks_on_login() throws Throwable {

    }

    @Then("^search should login successfully\\.$")
    public void search_should_login_successfully() throws Throwable {

    }

    @Then("^closes the browser$")
    public void closes_the_browser() throws Throwable {

    }

}
```

Logical Implementation:

package com.ibepages;

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class StackExchangePage {

    WebDriver localDriver;

    public StackExchangePage(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/chromedriver");
        localDriver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    public void openURL(String url) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.print("the URL is --> " + url);
        localDriver.navigate().to(url);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    }

    public void enterUserName (String username) {
        localDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='email']")).clear();
        localDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='email']")).sendKeys(username);
    }

    public void enterPassword(String password) {
        localDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='pass']")).clear();
        localDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='pass']")).sendKeys(password);
    }


}
```

Comment: Thank you Sandeep for your help :)